# Haskell List.insert is applied to too few arguments

Tags: haskell

So, I am working on a function that takes two lists already in order from smallest to biggest and merge them in  way that they are both sorted.  My thinking was to split the second list into head and tail, use insert to sort the head into the first list, and run the function again.  However upon running I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `[a0] -> [a0]'
    In the return type of a call of `List.insert'
    Probable cause: `List.insert' is applied to too few arguments
```

I am a bit confused as to how I should solve this, here is the code:

```
combsort((x:xs):(y:ys)) = combsort(List.insert(y (x:xs)) : ys)
combsort((x:xs):[]) = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one set of parentheses too many,

```
combsort((x:xs):(y:ys)) = combsort(List.insert(y (x:xs)) : ys)
```

should be

```
combsort ((x:xs):(y:ys)) = combsort (List.insert y (x:xs) : ys)
```

Note that function application doesn't need parentheses.

In your original, the `List.insert(y (x:xs))` is parsed as `List.insert` applied to the result of applying `y` to the list `(x:xs)`, like

```
List.insert foo
  where
    foo = y (x:xs)
```

Comment: New problem now then, `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0] In the first argument of List.insert', namely y`
`

Comment: Ah, bad pattern. In `combsort ((x:xs):(y:ys))`, let the type of `x` be `a`. Then `y :: [a]` and `ys :: [[a]]`. I'm not sure how you intend your algorithm to work (How would one implement comb sort for a list without becoming pathetically inefficient?), so I'm not sure what the correct fix is. What is the intention?

Comment: The intention is to take a 2 element list, each of the elements themselves being lists, and merge them together.  I split up the second list into y:ys (y being head, ys being tail) and insert y into (x:xs), the first list using insertion sort and add the second list (ys) back to the list of lists as the second element, then run the function again until the second list is empty.  Also combsort is short for combine and sort.

Comment: Okay, then it would be e.g. `combsort (xs : [y:ys]) = combsort (insert y xs : [ys])`. That's not a comb sort, however, and your other case should be `combsort (xs : [[]]) = xs`. However, using specifically lists of length 2 is not the best way, it would be better to pass two arguments to the function.